# Get stats yearly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing an application with php/MySQL and I need to get stats yearly, grouped by a statut.

But, the year don't start at 01-01 to 31-12 but 01-08 to 31-07.

The table where I get data is like this :

```
create table Archive (
    id 
    dates (xx-xx-xxxx)  
    statut text
)
```

and the table stats is like :

```
create table stats (
    id int,
    dates text something like (2013-2014)  
    statut,
)

I found this query :
```

And I do this :

```
SELECT *, date_format(dates,'%Y') as date, count(id) as nbId from archive group by statut, date
```

But I don't know how to get stat for 01-08 to 31-07

Sorry for my English and thank you for your answer.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0):

First step is to create a Calendar table in your database and use it in your queries.

**STEP 1:**

Do a MySQL query with date limits like some arbitrary date in the future (31st December, 2040) and the beginning of this year or maybe 2013 (1st January, 2014)

```
SELECT datediff('2040-12-31','2014-01-01');
```

You will need the value that that query gives you. The above query return 9861.

**STEP 2:**

Now create the actual calendar table. You'll need not only dates, but also various fields that can be used to set additional data associated with each date, such as holidays, weekends, paydays, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE calendar (
    dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    y SMALLINT NULL,
    q tinyint NULL,
    m tinyint NULL,
    d tinyint NULL,
    dw tinyint NULL,
    monthName VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    dayName VARCHAR(9) NULL,
    w tinyint NULL,
    isWeekday BINARY(1) NULL,
    isHoliday BINARY(1) NULL,
    holidayDescr VARCHAR(32) NULL,
    isPayday BINARY(1) NULL
);
```

**STEP 3:**

Populate the table

```
CREATE TABLE ints ( i tinyint );

INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

INSERT INTO calendar (dt)
SELECT DATE('2010-01-01') + INTERVAL a.i*10000 + b.i*1000 + c.i*100 + d.i*10 + e.i DAY
FROM ints a JOIN ints b JOIN ints c JOIN ints d JOIN ints e
WHERE (a.i*10000 + b.i*1000 + c.i*100 + d.i*10 + e.i) <= 9861 #VALUE GOTTEN EARLIER
ORDER BY 1;
```

Basically, this populates the table with values you need. There are other things to do to populate the table with values for payday, holidays etc.

Then you can run a query like:

```
SELECT `count(id)` as `nbid`, `date`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `calendar`
    WHERE `dt` > `date` 
    ) AS `somethingdate`
FROM `archives`;
```